# how to monitor XCache Performance

Tags: php, xcache

In phpinfo, there is a list of directives but they are not changing at all

I see XCache is there by 'php -v'

But how can I monitor the caching? Like how many scripts are cached or how much space/memory it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default xcache admin page to get statistics and details on cached objects.

Please read the official [HOW-TO](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/InstallAdministration#HowtoInstallXCacheAdministrationPage).

You could either write your own script using [XCache API](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/XcacheApi#XCacheAPIsexportedtoPHPscript).

Comment: Have had the idea XCache had been using a lot of memory on my PHP 5.2 Fast CGI Setup. Now that I use PHP 5.3 CGI and no XCache the memory usage has gone down a lot. Will try this tool when Dreamhost has added XCache to PHP 5.3 unless they go for APC..